# Show itemRenderer in specific DataGrid rows... others empty

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a DataGrid populated via an Array.  The last column in the DataGrid uses an ItemRenderer (Button).  I want to show the Button in certain rows but not in others (leave those empty).  I've looked everywhere for an example or even a clue how to do this (tried labelFunction on DG, etc.) but can't find anything about it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay... with (lots of) help, figured it out.
First off, I'm not sure why the itemRenderer requires a container but it does.  The array must also be checked from the itemRenderer and not from the main application... again, I don't know why since the debugger shows it going through the exact same loop/events, etc.).
If interested here's the relevant parts of the code:

Main App:---

{col1:'', col2:'', col3:'', col4:'', col5:'', col6:'', col7: '', col8:'', col9:'', col10:'', col11:'**yo**'}];

public function initData():void
{ xferSchedule.dataProvider = schedArray; }
]]>

Answer (score 0):

an item renderer does not have to be a container, it has to implement `IDataRenderer` (a `Button` does not). One could extend `Button` and implement this interface to get a simple button renderer. If you want it to display conditionally, you will accomplish this by handling those conditions within the renderer based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Now this might get slightly complex. I would recommend you to define you an XML instead of Array of Objects. If the node has the type property button, then it would **create** button at that cell whose value type is button.

**How to create a button dynamically inside a grid which is yet again dynamic?**

This might end into the whole component being dynamic.